# Add images into an array JPanel

Tags: java, image, jpanel

I have made a chessboard out of JPanel. Using ImageIcon doesn't work, so I looked over the site, but all of it seems complicated, how do I add images to an array like

```
tiles[0][0].setIcon(br);
```

This is the JPanel that I created for the chessboard

```
private JPanel[][] tiles = new JPanel[6][6];
```

I have tried this:

```
    ImageIcon bn = new ImageIcon("art/BN.gif");
    ImageIcon bb = new ImageIcon("art/BB.gif");
    ImageIcon br = new ImageIcon("art/BR.gif");
    ImageIcon wn = new ImageIcon("art/WN.gif");
    ImageIcon wb = new ImageIcon("art/WB.gif");
    ImageIcon wr = new ImageIcon("art/WR.gif");
    tiles[0][0].add(new JLabel(bn));
    tiles[0][1].add(new JLabel(wn));
    tiles[0][2].add(new JLabel(wb));
    tiles[0][3].add(new JLabel(wb));
    tiles[0][4].add(new JLabel(wn));
    tiles[0][5].add(new JLabel(wr));
    tiles[5][0].add(new JLabel(br));
    tiles[5][1].add(new JLabel(bn));
    tiles[5][2].add(new JLabel(bb));
    tiles[5][3].add(new JLabel(bb));
    tiles[5][4].add(new JLabel(bn));
    tiles[5][5].add(new JLabel(br));
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: can you see the panels?can you see the labels?is there any errors?

Comment: @Fast SnailCant see the labels

Comment: is ambs's answer  working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are your images being stored? What exactly doesn't work?

I'm going to take a shot in the dark and assume you're attempting to load files that are embedded in your application.

Taken from; https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

> ```
> ImageIcon(String filename)
> ```
>
> Creates an ImageIcon from the specified file.
>
> ```
> ImageIcon(URL location)
> ```
>
> Creates an ImageIcon from the specified URL.

Try this;

```
ImageIcon bn = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("art/BN.gif"));
```

It will attempt to create an ImageIcon from a URL returned by .getResource()